# Start automatically python webserver from visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, simplehttpserver

I would like to start automatically Python http.server when I'm hitting the run button (or F5) from visual studio code.
I assume it's the matter of the launch.json configuration but I'm not familiar with it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the pythonVSCode extension. And create python file in your project directory. And place the below content on it. Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

And create launch configuration like this...

```
{
    "name": "Documentation",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/env/bin/python",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/your_pyton_run_file.py",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
},
```

Then you can start this with F5

Comment: Would t be possible to add a link to the extension? I just googled pythonVSCode and multiple extension come up. I would assume they might not all work the way the one you suggest does.

Comment: @Chillie I've not tested the vscode python webserver recently. And pythonVSCode repo migrated to microsoft. This is the link https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python